# textwrap.dedent not working when there are newlines

Tags: python, string

I am confused to why textwrap.dedent doesn't work when the `details` variable contains `\n` or newlines but it works if there are none. Is there a workaround to make this work?

```
from textwrap import dedent

log_msg = {
    'log_id': 'testid',
    'log_level': 'CRITICAL',
    'message': 'Complete export to no_cat_products.csv',
    'details': 'asdasdasdasdasdasd\n[asdasdasdasdasd\nasdasdasd\n',
    'source_application': 'testing.py',
    'timestamp': 123445657
}

message = dedent(f"""
    ID: {log_msg['log_id']}
    Log Level: {log_msg['log_level']}
    Message: {log_msg['message']}

    Details:
    {dedent(log_msg['details'])}

    Source Application: {log_msg['source_application']}
    Created: {log_msg['timestamp']}
""")

print(message)
```

Output

```
        ID: testid
        Log Level: CRITICAL
        Message: Complete export to no_cat_products.csv

        Details:
        asdasdasdasdasdasd
[asdasdasdasdasd
asdasdasd


        Source Application: testing.py
        Created: 123445657
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `lstrip` on each line split by `'\n'`

```
print('\n'.join([m.lstrip() for m in message.split('\n')]))
```

Comment: This works great. Thanks so much. I'll look into lstrip as well.

Comment: It just removes spaces to the left of a string. Look into `strip` and `rstrip` as well if you are not familiar with these functions

Answer (score 5):

`textwrap.dedent` removes indentation *common to all non-blank lines* of its input. It doesn't just remove all indentation completely.

Your string contains non-blank lines with no indentation whatsoever, because `log_msg['details']` is several lines long. There is no indentation common to all the non-blank lines.

The right way to fix this depends on exactly what you were trying to do in the first place.

- If you wanted to remove all indentation completely, including indentation that was in the original `log_msg['details']` string, then `dedent` is the wrong tool - perhaps you should split the string by lines, `lstrip` every line, and put them back together.
- If you were expecting all lines to have the same leading indentation before the `dedent` call, then maybe you need to build your string differently.
- If you wanted your code to behave as if the format string itself had no indentation, then you should write a format string with no indentation, or use `str.format` instead of f-strings and apply `dedent` *before* formatting.

Comment: I want to remove all indentation completely. I am now using `lstrip()`. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround but I'm not sure if it's best practice. It works either way.

```
message = dedent(f"""
    ID: {log_msg['log_id']}
    Log Level: {log_msg['log_level']}
    Message: {log_msg['message']}
""") + 'Details:\n' + log_msg['details'] + dedent(f"""
    Source Application: {log_msg['source_application']}
    Created: {log_msg['timestamp']}
""")
```